# Problem in Selenium Browserstack session: loading existing Chrome profile

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, whatsapp, browserstack

I am running a test with Selenium (Python) remotely on Browserstack Automate.

**Goal**: I want to start a session on Browserstack, with an existing Chrome profile logged in.

- *-- Underlying goal: I am trying to access Whatsapp Web without having to scan the QR code every single time. (Building an automated Whatsapp service)*

So it would be ok to have a new profile made the first time - scan the QR code once  and then re-use that profile afterwards.

**Method**: I try to use Chrome Options, and specify an argument for user-data-dir. This was inspired by several other StackOverflow answers.

Code:

```
desired_caps = {
    'browser': 'Chrome',
    'browser_version': '69.0 beta',
    'os': 'Windows',
    'os_version': '10',
    'resolution': '1024x768',
    'browserstack.debug': 'true',
}
desired_caps['browserstack.local'] = True
desired_caps['chromeOptions'] = {}       
desired_caps['chromeOptions']['args'] = [r'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\gille\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data']
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://MYBROWSERSTACKHUB', desired_capabilities=desired_caps)
```

I am trying to run this on Browserstack (locally), but I am getting the following error when running:

"Could not initialize class org.openqa.selenium.os.Kernel32"

[See image with Browserstack error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wGlS.png)

I have tried specifying a new random profile that did not exist yet, e.g.:

```
desired_caps['chromeOptions']['args'] = [r'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\gille\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ProfileXXX']
```

But the same error pops up.

(I have also tried other methods that did not work for me:
 - Saving and re-loading cookies
 - Changing the session_id and session_url (does not work on Browserstack) )

I feel that:
 - or this could be a problem with Browserstack, 
 - or I am including the wrong path for user-data-dir, and should go with a different, e.g. chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])

But I am unfamiliar with the last one - So I am unsure what the next step to take is. 
**Do you have any advice?**

Answer (score 0):

Use the caps as below:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(CloudConfiguration.URL), caps);
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer; I don't really see how your code is different from mine?

I am using Browserstack to run the test, so I need to set the caps in a specific way according to that syntax.

Could you explain a bit further?

Comment: just wondering why you have used character 'r' in the args value

Comment: I see! That's to avoid a Unicode error (truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape).

I have re-tried without the r, but double slash: C:\\Users\\gille\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data

But same result for now...