# Open Profile in Chrome Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to open profile in selenium (for login in whatsapp for once) like the below code but when run my code chrome open a second tab with this url:http://%3D%20c/Users/Ali/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User%20Data/Default

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

PATH = "chromedriver.exe"
url = "https://web.whatsapp.com/"
CH_Option = ChromeOptions()
CH_Option.add_argument("user-data-dir = C:/Users/Ali/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default")

Driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH,options=CH_Option)
Driver.get(url)
```

[......ScreenShot.....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaExf.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you try calling the `add_argument` method with a raw (literal) string, e.g. `CH_Option.add_argument(r"user-data-dir = C:/example")`?

Comment: @VirtualScooter Thanks Mate
you mean just put a 'r' before location string ?
i did it but nothing changed

Comment: Actually, you might want to consider removing the spaces. An example that worked before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52777900/5660315.

Comment: @VirtualScooter yeah it worked,I removed spaces in that string and chrome opened my profile, Thank You...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, change the `add_argument` line to (removing the spaces in the string):

```
CH_Option.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/Ali/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to change `/` in your path to `\\`

```
CH_Option.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Ali\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default")
```

2. Try to create a Guest user profile in your chrome driver and change the path to

```
CH_Option.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Ali\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Guest Profile")
```